# Visual Studio 2019 it was not possible to load the application configuration data. please check if the file 'runtime.config' exists and is correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

C# after successfully build, while executing the application, the following error appears

> Visual Studio 2019: it was not possible to load the application configuration data. Please check if the file 'runtime.config' exists and is correct

Please help me to find the problem

Comment: Please provide more context - what kind of app is this? Which version of the .NET framework are you targeting? Do you have a config file? Can you provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: No, please *edit your question* to include not just the configuration file, but all the rest of the information.

Comment: I am using C# desktop form application , .NetFramework version=4.7.2

Comment: Again, *edit the question*. That information shouldn't be in comments, it should be in the question itself.

Comment: And, what is a _"C# desktop form"_ application? WinForms? WPF? UWP?